# including external js file into angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a java script file that contains a config object for decoding a lot of business jargon for ease of use in my application.

How can I get that to be available to my angular app? I currently have it included in my html file above  all the application files.

here is my config.js:

```
var config = {
    "metadata":[
              "8235205241531AF399B113140005492E":{
                    "name":"verison_number"
               }
     ]
 }
```

here is includes:

```
        <script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/angular-resources/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/viewer.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

now here is my controller just trying to do a console.log on it:

```
var MainCtrl = angular.module('MainCtrl', []);


MainCtrl.controller('loader',['$scope','$rootScope','$http','startApp', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,startApp) {
    console.log(config);
    console.log('loading course...');
    console.log(startApp);
}]);
```

Comment: if you have it in the html that contains angular script then angular has the access if the config object is global.

Comment: do I need to inject it into my app? It's coming up as not defined.

Comment: @JasonSpick at least show some kind of code.

Comment: @JasonSpick the only way I can see that not working is if you haven't instantiated that controller with `ng-controller` on the current route. In other words - none of the controller code would be running at all.

Comment: Everything else logs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is incorrect.

Here is the correct way for declaring config:

```
var config = {
"metadata":[
    {"8235205241531AF399B113140005492E":"verison_number"}
]}
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2RlkgAMY8jVIdHf6UZ6P?p=preview)

Comment: Heheh, so obvious! Sometimes it's hard to see those. Good job!

Comment: I would update your answer that it is improper and bad for testing to use a global variable like that. He ought to set an angular service/value and inject it where needed.

Comment: Thanks @m59!! appreciate that! @Jasonspick: Have a working fiddle over here...I guess there might be an issue in some of the other js files. Is there any console error?

Comment: @JasonSpick: Which code is updated? the json appears to be the same that you had earlier?

Comment: no, I didn't have objects in the array. I think what I am struggling with is getting the array to read key value.

Comment: This is an invalid json structure. You cannot have key value to array, it has to be an array of objects if you desire this type of structure or simply remove the array and have objects only, similar to what its here http://plnkr.co/edit/2RlkgAMY8jVIdHf6UZ6P?p=preview

Comment: you are right. I've done this before with objects, but not json. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the value recipe. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('MainCtrl');

// later

app.value('myconfigs',config); // set your "object"

// somewhere in your controller code

MainCtrl.controller('loader',['$scope','$rootScope','$http','startApp','myconfigs', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,startApp, myconfig) {
    console.log(myconfig.metadata);
    console.log('loading course...');
    console.log(startApp);
}]);
```

Comment: That isn't going to solve the problem. If `config` is truly undefined, then you're just setting the `value` to undefined.